# c++11 variadic template fail to compile

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Just a few lines of code, I wish "count" function will give the number of parameters:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
size_t f(T&& ... elem){
    return sizeof...(elem);
}
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

But it fails to compile

```
main.cpp:5:22: error: expansion pattern 'T&&' contains no argument packs
size_t count(T&& ... elem){
                    ^~~~
main.cpp: In function 'size_t count()':
main.cpp:6:22: error: 'elem' has not been declared
    return sizeof...(elem);
                    ^~~~
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:23: error: no matching function for call to 'count(int, int, int)'
    return count(1,2,3);
                    ^
main.cpp:5:8: note: candidate: 'template<class T> size_t count()'
size_t count(T&& ... elem){
        ^~~~~
main.cpp:5:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:9:23: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
    return count(1,2,3);
                    ^


g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
Compile, link and run...
Share!
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to introduce the template parameter pack with `...`, too:

```
template<class... T>         // declares the pack "T"
//            ^^^
size_t f(T&&... elem)        // declares the pack "elem", uses the pack "T"
{
    return sizeof...(elem);  // ("sizeof..." is an operator)
}
```